# How to show result on button click in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Consider me a very beginner App developer who has not developed anything so far :)
I like to "number"x2 (multiply by 2) shows up in front of "result" **after clicking** "Calculation" button. 
also, how can I show the result on another page/screen? 
here is a pic of the app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QleQ4.png)

here is my code:
MainPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout>


    <Label
            Text="Give me a number"
            Margin="0,50,0,0" Padding="13,0,0,0"/>

    <Entry Placeholder="number"
           x:Name="numb"
           Keyboard="Numeric"
           Margin="130,-30,40,0"
           Opacity="1" Rotation="0"
           TranslationX="16" />

    <Button Text="  Calculate  "
            BackgroundColor="#F6DEDE"
            FontSize="Large"
            FontAttributes="Bold" 
            />
    <Label
        Text=" Result "
        FontSize="30"
        Margin="0, 20, 0, 0"
        Padding="10,0,0,0"/>

</StackLayout>
```

Here is MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
         public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
      void CalculateClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
       {
           float numb = float.Parse(this.numb.Text);

            float B = 100 * numb * 2;
            // show B in front of result or on another page

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you need is to use the [MVVM pattern](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjFxcv5v4vpAhXVQc0KHSOuB7UQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fxamarin%2Fxamarin-forms%2Fenterprise-application-patterns%2Fmvvm&usg=AOvVaw07M_C9bcF__xpkN4bb9v0J). You would have a view and a viewmodel. When the user taps the button, the "business logic" in your viewmodel is being executed that multiplies the value by two and then sets result label accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the two answers already points out, you need to give a name to the label in xaml and then you can use it in code behind to set the text.

```
void CalculateClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    float numb = float.Parse(this.numb.Text);

    float B = 100 * numb * 2;
    // show B in front of result or on another page

    resultLabel.Text = B.ToString();
}
```

Another thing you need to do is add a click event to the button and assign `CalculateClicked` to it. Then when you click the button, `CalculateClicked` method will be triggered:

```
<Button Text="  Calculate  "
    BackgroundColor="#F6DEDE"
    FontSize="Large"
    FontAttributes="Bold" 

    Clicked="CalculateClicked"

    />
```

Answer (score 1):

first, give a name to your Label

```
<Label x:Name="result"
    Text=" Result "
    FontSize="30"
    Margin="0, 20, 0, 0"
    Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
```

Now, you have to set the result in the label

```
   void CalculateClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
   {
       float numb = float.Parse(this.numb.Text);

       float B = 100 * numb * 2;

       result.Text = $": {B}";
    }
```

Comment: I also need to add Clicked="CalculateClicked" to my button. Thanks 4 ur help

Answer (score 0):

first, give your `Label` a name

```
<Label x:Name="lblResult"
    Text=" Result "
    FontSize="30"
    Margin="0, 20, 0, 0"
    Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
```

then you can assign it a value from code

```
void CalculateClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
   {
       float numb = float.Parse(this.numb.Text);

        float B = 100 * numb * 2;
        // show B in front of result or on another page

        lblResult.Text += ": " + B.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. you just missed part Clicked="CalculateClicked". Anyway thanks 4 ur help